# Auto upgrade Gem Versions in GemFile with Rails upgrade

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm upgrading my Rails application to 5.0 (5.0.0.1 current latest), I've also upgraded my Ruby version to `2.3.0p0` and bundler version to `1.13.6`,

Now when I run `bundle update` it throws error like

```
devise (= 4.2.0) was resolved to 4.2.0, which depends on
      railties (< 5.1, >= 4.1.0)
```

and so, I'd like to know if there is any automated way to auto update my gem version in gem file since I have around 100 gems in the `GemFile`

Comment: bundle update can also work

Comment: @WishZone it didnt work for me

Comment: Then you have to remove gem.lock file and then do bundle ... it will update all dependencies

Comment: you can also do bundle update devise , if there is one gem conflct

Comment: deleting Gemfile.lock doesnt work either

Comment: Have you mentioned the devise version in gem file if yes then remove the version, as it will update the newest one, then do the above thing again

Answer (score 0):

I would go with

```
$ bundle update
```

Because if gems you have specified in your Gemfile hasn't specified version, it will update your gems with latest available, and gems which has specified version with '~>' last patched version, for example from 1.0.1 to 1.0.2.

Also note, that bundle install will only install gems or missing gems specified in your gemfile, where bundle update will ugrade all gems managed with bundler.

Final, but that is just my opinion, I would wait with upgrading to Rails 5, just because not all gems are actually tested and upgraded to work with Rails 5.

Answer (score 0):

**You can do following things**

- Delete the GemLock file and do `bundle install`

OR

- Do `bundle update`

**If Still its not fixed**

- Remove the devise version that you have mentioned in GemFile and so `bundle install` so that it will automatically pick up the new version